# aligning input text boxes in html

Tags: html, css

How do I align my text boxes in html? I have tried everything. The age box should start at the same location as Name and Email and it should be the same size as those two boxes. Please help if you can. I made the width of each input text box the same to ensure its the same size and tried to have the text boxes start at the same location. Thanks!

```css
#Title{
  text-align: center;
}
#description{
  text-align: center;
}
body{
  background-color: #7FFFD4;
}
#Survey-form{
  background-color: f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
}
.nameageemail
{
  clear: both;
  margin: right;
  margin:0px auto;

}
#Name{
  text-align: left;
  width: 200;
  height: 25;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:30px;

}
#Email{
  text-align: left;
  width: 200;
  height: 25;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:30px;


}
#Age{
  text-align: left;
  width: 200;
  height: 25;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:30px;


}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Survey Form </title>
<!-- Survey Form. -->
<link href="SurveyForm.css" rel=stylesheet>

</head>
<body>

  <h1 id="Title"> Survey Form </h1>


  <form id="Survey-form">
    <p id="description">Let us know how we can improve freeCodeCamp </p>

<div class="nameageemail">
  <p> <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Enter your name"> </p>
  <label>Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Enter your email"><br>
<p><label> Age:</label>
  <input type="number" min = "18" max="110" name="Age" id="Age" placeholder="Age"></p>
</div>
    
    
</form>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: You're missing the units (`px`) on the `width`s and `height`s for your form fields.

Comment: You didn't add units to any of your widths and heights. E.g. `width: 200;` should be `width: 200px;`.

Comment: Use a table to organize your form.

Comment: @Bhanu Tables are for tabular data, not layout

Comment: I'm trying to develop this but not having luck. https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/details/VPaoNP

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table-based display values to layout your form.

Also, some values were missing units and a color was missing the #.

```css
body > * {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: #7FFFD4;
}

.survey-form {
  display: block;
}

.survey-form > div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: initial;
  padding: 8px;
}

.survey-form > div > p {
  display: table-row;
}

.survey-form > div > p > * {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 8px;
}

.survey-form input {
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 1px 8px;
}

.instructions {
  display: initial !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Survey Form </title>
  <!-- Survey Form. -->
  <!-- REMOVED FOR SNIPPET
    <link href="SurveyForm.css" rel=stylesheet>
  -->

</head>

<body>

  <h1> Survey Form </h1>

  <form class="survey-form" action="">
    <div>
      <p class="instructions">
        Let us know how we can improve freeCodeCamp
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="Name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Enter your name">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="Email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Enter your email">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="Name">Age:</label>
        <input type="number" min="18" max="110" name="Age" id="Age" placeholder="Age">
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>


</body>

</html>
```